# How to grayout all tableview cells except selected one

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a table view with custom cells ,there are uibuttons on custom cell ,if i select button except that cell remaining all cells should be grayouted or disabled is it possible.

// code in tableview class

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
NSLog(@"No OF rows:%d",[contents count]);
return [contents count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

// Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
cell = (uploadCustomCell *)[tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"uploadCustomCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"cell allocated");
    // Use the default cell style.

    cell = [[uploadCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"uploadCustomCell"];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"uploadCustomCell"
                                                        owner:self options:nil];


  cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
   saveBtnCcell.hidden = YES;
   cell.textNamefield.hidden = YES;
 [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
[cell.defaultSwitch setEnabled:NO];
   dictionaryContents = [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"dict dict :%@",dictionaryContents);
  //

   cell
.nameLabelCell.text   = [dictionaryContents valueForKey:@"VideoName"];
    cell.userName.text = [dictionaryContents valueForKey:@"User"];
  NSLog(@"Array Image:%@",arrayimage);
  cell.thumbImg.image = [arrayimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"ARimage:%@,index%d",[arrayimage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],indexPath.row);
   NSString *defaultVideo = [dictionaryContents valueForKey:@"DefaultVideo"];
NSLog(@"Default Video:%@",defaultVideo);
if ([defaultVideo isEqual: @"1"]) {
    //        [cell.defaultSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    [defaultSwitche setOn:YES animated:YES];

}
else{
      //        [cell.defaultSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    [defaultSwitche setOn:NO animated:YES];
}

   [cell.defaultSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



VideoNameTextField.hidden = YES;

   return cell;


}
```

// Code in customcell

```
  @interface uploadCustomCell (){
UploadAllViewController *uploadAll;
}

@end
@implementation uploadCustomCell
@synthesize textNamefield;
@synthesize savebtn,edit,nameLabelCell,textLabel,uploadBTN;
@synthesize defaultSwitch;
//@synthesize uploadAll;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}


- (void)dealloc {
[_userName release];

[_thumbImg release];

  //[savebtn release];
[textNamefield release];
[nameLabelCell release];
[_test release];

[savebtn release];
[defaultSwitch release];
[uploadBTN release];
[super dealloc];
}


- (IBAction)editAction:(id)sender {
[uploadBTN setEnabled:NO];
uploadAll = [[UploadAllViewController alloc]init];
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:uploadAll.tabelView1];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [uploadAll.tabelView1 indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
int no = indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"index path :%d",no);
[uploadAll didEditButtonPressed:self];

}
- (IBAction)saveBtnAction:(id)sender {
 [uploadBTN setEnabled:YES];
[uploadAll didSaveButtonPressed:self];
}
```

when i select this editAction: except that cell remaining cells should be grayouted.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. To be able to help you, you need to provide more information and code. Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions to understand what kind of questions you can ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have to account for the state of your table view, i.e. if one or zero cells are selected. Use that to change the appearance of your cell as you wish. In the example below I have assumed you are having a straight array without any sections, but the same principle would work with `indexPath`s as well. I use an `int` `selectedRow` set to `-1` if there is no cell selected.

```
#define kNoCellSelected -1

// in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

if (self.selectedRow == kNoCellSelected) {
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = normalColor;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
else if (self.selectedRow != indexPath.row) {
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = disabledColor;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Don't forget to set `selectedRow` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: if we use this code in cell for row  at indexpath we are not reloading table each time i press button.

Comment: That is not what this code does. You have to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` in your button method. However, it will only work if you configure each cell dynamically as above.